# Как преобразовать объект в строку для отображения на html странице?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Даются различные объекты, например:

`const myObj = [['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','j','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p']];`

Нужно отображать их на странице сайта. Я написал вот такую функцию, для преобразования объекта в строку:

```
const objToString = () => {                            
    let a = '[';
    let l = myObj.length;
    for (let i of myObj){
          a += '[ ' + i + ' ]';
          l -= 1;
          if(l > 0){
                  a += ','
          }
    }
    a += ']'
    return a + '<br> to create a table from an object';};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть метод по-проще? Так как обычное  toString()  не работает (((

Comment: [JSON.stringify](https://dev.to/blacksonic/the-secret-power-of-json-stringify-393b) подойдёт?

Comment: а что должно получиться на выходе (наведите пример)?

Comment: Это же не объект, двумерный массив. Не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное самый простой способ

```js
const myObj = [['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','j','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p']];
document.getElementById('code').innerText = JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 4)
```

```html
<pre id="code">
</pre>
```

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, это действительно двумерный массив )))) Но ваше решение работает! )))))

Comment: Благодарю, что дали направление для реализации решения.

Действительно если  записать:

`document.getElementById('code').innerText = JSON.stringify(myObj)`

то в итоге, на странице отобразится:

`[['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','j','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p']]`

Answer (score 0):

что должно быть на выходе-то ?

```js
const myObj = [['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','j','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p']];
let imploded = myObj.join(`,`);
console.log(imploded);
```

Comment: Нет не в консоль нужно вывести, а на веб-страницу, в виде:

"myObj = [['a','b','c','d'], ['e','f','j','h'], ['i','j','k','l'], ['m','n','o','p']]"